# Cropping images using ImageMagick results in all output files (TIF) of same size?

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I am scanning a rare old book (cookbook) for archiving using my Canon LiDE 110. The scans are `.TIF` files, and I want to batch crop them for uniformity, et cetera.

This is how I am doing the batch cropping using ImageMagick:

```
mogrify -gravity North -crop 1600x2512+0+0 -type Palette -define tiff:rows-per-strip=16 -define tiff:subfiletype=PAGE *.tif
```

*(The additional command-line options such as `type`, `rows-per-strip` and `subfiletype` were used to keep the properties identical to the original images.)*

I've also tried cropping each file at a time like so:

```
mogrify -gravity North -crop 1600x2512+0+0 -type Palette -define tiff:rows-per-strip=16 -define tiff:subfiletype=PAGE IMG_0003.tif
```

**The problem is** that the resultant (output) cropped images are all of the same size in bytes! (All are 4,022,366 bytes to be exact.)

Original Images **<sup>[1]</sup>**:

```
$ identify *.tif

IMG_0002.tif TIFF 1660x2572 1660x2572+0+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.273MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0003.tif TIFF 1652x2556 1652x2556+0+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.226MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0004.tif TIFF 1656x2572 1656x2572+0+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.262MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0005.tif TIFF 1668x2604 1668x2604+0+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.347MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0006.tif TIFF 1680x2544 1680x2544+0+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.277MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Cropped Images:

```
$ identify *.tif

IMG_0002.tif TIFF 1600x2512 1600x2512+30+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.022MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0003.tif TIFF 1600x2512 1600x2512+26+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.022MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0004.tif TIFF 1600x2512 1600x2512+28+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.022MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0005.tif TIFF 1600x2512 1600x2512+34+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.022MB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG_0006.tif TIFF 1600x2512 1600x2512+40+0 16-bit sRGB 256c 4.022MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Why could this be happening?**

---

**Footnotes:**

1. For the sake of identifying the problem in the question (if any) I am temporarily making the original files publicly available, here:

   - <del>https://s3.amazonaws.com/myqtemp/IMG_0002.tif</del>
   - <del>https://s3.amazonaws.com/myqtemp/IMG_0003.tif</del>
   - <del>https://s3.amazonaws.com/myqtemp/IMG_0004.tif</del>
   - <del>https://s3.amazonaws.com/myqtemp/IMG_0005.tif</del>
   - <del>https://s3.amazonaws.com/myqtemp/IMG_0006.tif</del>

   **<del>These will be deleted once the question has an acceptable answer/resolution</del> Deleted.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mogrify` command crops the image to a fixed size. It also [removes any compression](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28618#p127136) present in the image, mainly to avoid recompressing JPEG images and losing image quality. It also ensures the resulting TIFF is fully compatible with the [baseline format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Part_1:_Baseline_TIFF).

The result is that you will get very similarly sized files for each of your scans:

x_pixels * y_pixels * bytes_per_pixel

In your case x_pixels=1600, y_pixels=2512, and bytes_per_pixel=1 because you've specified a fixed colour palette. Allowing for metadata and the palette map, the resulting file sizes will all be a little larger than 4,019,200 bytes:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 4225562 Dec 30 16:28 IMG_0003.tif    # Original
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 4022354 Jan  5 09:55 IMG_0003.tif    # Mogrified
```

You can see that the metadata and palette take an additional 203,208 bytes above the theoretical minimum size.

Now, there are a [number of extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Part_2:_TIFF_Extensions) to the TIFF format, one of which allows for a number of different types of compression. These compression types can be applied with the `-compress {type}` flag to `mogrify`. Some of these compression types are lossy, others are lossless. Here are some comparative sizes for the lossless options:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 4022354 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif    # None
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 4022354 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif    # BZip
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 446952 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif     # LZW
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 594040 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif     # RLE
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 429692 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif     # Zip
-rw-r--r--+ 1 roaima users 478622 Jan  5 10:02 IMG_0003.tif     # LZMA
```

Unexpectedly, BZip compression appears to fail - at least on my system - but I have not been able to find any other instance of this reported via my preferred search engine.

The net result is that if you modify your `mogrify` command slightly you will get lossless TIFF files at a greatly reduced size:

```
mogrify -gravity North -crop 1600x2512+0+0 -type Palette \
-define tiff:rows-per-strip=16 -define tiff:subfiletype=PAGE -compress Zip *.tif
```